# Bound of a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a diffeomorphism such that $\phi(0) = 0$.

> Why does there exist a constant $C \ge 1$ such that
>
> $$ {1\over C} |x| \le |\phi (x) | \le C |x|$$
>
> on some open ball containing $0$?

It's clear to me that on some open ball containing zero we have $|\phi (x) | \le C$ (because $\phi$ is continuous) but this is much weaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, $\phi'(0)\neq 0$, that is, the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\phi(x)}x$$
exists but it is not $0$. Moreover, $\phi'(0)$ is precisely this limit. Take any positive $\epsilon<|\phi'(0)|$, $\epsilon=|\phi'(0)|/2$, for example. Then there exists some $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\phi(x)}{x}-\phi'(0)\right|<\epsilon$$
In other words, if $x$ is in the open ball $(-\delta,\delta)$ then
$$(\phi'(0)-\epsilon)|x|\le|\phi(x)|\le(\phi'(0)+\epsilon)|x|$$

So it suffices to take
$$C=\max\left\{\frac1{\phi'(0)-\epsilon},\phi'(0)+\epsilon\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $\phi'(0)\ne0$ (otherwise $\phi^{-1}$ would not be differentiable at $x=0$.)